# Custom Application specific Keyboard in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a custom keyboard for my application. ie. consider a simple text input and when I click on that, I want a custom keyboard to appear. For ex : a dialler like keyboard, having keys 0-9 and then some custom buttons for my application. Is it possible to do that in android?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  There are two ways to approach this:

1. Create your own input method (keyboard) - here's an example on google of how this can be done: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html - you'll then need to set this keyboard as an IME in your app.
2. Create your own view with a bunch of buttons to handle your own stuff.  This won't be a "keyboard" in a true android way, but it would do everything you need for your app.  I have seen apps that contain their own "keyboards" designed in this way.

In addition, keep in mind that even the basic android keyboard has several "versions" available: alpha, keypad, symbols, etc.

Which way you prefer to go depends on your specific needs, your development abilities and time constraints.

Comment: The challenge with an input method is you can't show it unless the user long-taps the EditText and then selects the custom input method.

Comment: @EricBurke You are probably right.  However it's still a valid method.  Most likely for his purposes he'd be better off with method 2.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own view with a bunch of buttons to handle your own stuff. This won't be a "keyboard" in a true android way, but it would do everything you need for your app. I have seen apps that contain their own "keyboards" designed in this way.

In addition, keep in mind that even the basic android keyboard has several "versions" available: alpha, keypad, symbols, etc.

Which way you prefer to go depends on your specific needs, your development abilities and time constraints.